# with android maps api v2 ,how to track user location ( similar to how google maps api track ) . The user location marker always remain in center

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

using google android api v2, how do we track/follow user location like the google maps app does. The user location marker stays in the center.
Currently I am using

mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(isEnabled);

and

mUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(isEnabled);

By using these two, I am able to show user location and button which centers the user on map.But if user is moving, the location arrow goes out of the screen.

I can fix this by listening to LocationListener and animate the map to new location. 
Is there any other way then this ????

This task was  quite easy if using iPhone maps api.

Comment: IMO everything is quite is in iPhone development. :) I know this comment isn't helpful. I came here looking for an answer as well. Just wanted to point that out I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Google finally added `OnMyLocationChangeListener`, which is called when a change in location is detected. So now automatic centering of the camera is a trivial task.